# RESTful Api - Spring MediaType vs Restlet MediaType

Tags: java, spring, rest, restlet

I have an REST client:

```
import org.restlet.representation.ObjectRepresentation;
import org.restlet.data.MediaType;

ObjectRepresentation<ApprovalResponse> objectRepresentation = (ObjectRepresentation<ApprovalResponse>) cr.post(approvalRequest, MediaType.APPLICATION_JAVA_OBJECT);
```

And a Spring Boot Service RESTful api:

```
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;

@PostMapping(value = "/rest/approvals-submit")
public @ResponseBody ApprovalResponse submit(@RequestHeader(name="Authorization") String token, @RequestBody ApprovalRequest approvalRequest) {
    System.out.println("jwt token: "+token);
    System.out.println(approvalRequest.getMessageToEvaluator());
    ApprovalResponse approvalResponse = new ApprovalResponse();
    approvalResponse.setApprovalId("Test approvalResponse from micro service");
    return approvalResponse;
}
```

The client calls the API successfully. i.e. the `System.out.println(approvalRequest.getMessageToEvaluator());` is printed out successfully.

**Problem**

My issue is that the response object is not getting back to the REST client.

**Error Messages**

Rest client

> org.restlet.resource.ResourceException: Not Acceptable (406) - The
> resource identified by the request is only capable of generating
> response entities which have content characteristics not acceptable
> according to the accept headers sent in the request

Server/Api

> Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException:
> Could not find acceptable representation]

**Question**

So I think these errors are because the MediaTypes are not defined correctly.  Do you know what they should be defined as?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Update after having a direct chat

We added on the rest endpoint, on the postMapping annotation the following:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/rest/approvals-submit")
public @ResponseBody ApprovalResponse submit(@RequestHeader(name="Authorization") String token, @RequestBody ApprovalRequest approvalRequest, produces={MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE},consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE) {
    System.out.println("jwt token: "+token);
    System.out.println(approvalRequest.getMessageToEvaluator());
    ApprovalResponse approvalResponse = new ApprovalResponse();
    approvalResponse.setApprovalId("Test approvalResponse from micro service");
    return approvalResponse;
}
```

This added on the @PostMapping annotation produces={MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE},consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE.

On client side, we change the response type to Representation, and we were able to get the json response:

```
ClientResource cr = new ClientResource(endpointUrl);
ChallengeResponse challengeResponse = new ChallengeResponse(ChallengeScheme.HTTP_OAUTH_BEARER);
challengeResponse.setRawValue(token);
cr.setChallengeResponse(challengeResponse);

Request req = cr.getRequest();

Representation representation = cr.post(approvalRequest);
System.out.println(representation.getText());
```

Finally, [using Jackson Object Mapper](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-object-mapper-tutorial) the response could be mapped into the Approval response object:

```
    // now convert the response to java
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    ApprovalResponse approvalResponse = objectMapper.readValue(json, ApprovalResponse.class);
    System.out.println(approvalResponse);
    System.out.println(approvalResponse.getApprovalId());
```

It was a content negotiation issue. The content negotiation it's done via the Content-Type header, for better understanding of it, you could read [this blog entry](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-content-negotiation-json-xml)

Comment: Thanks. Here is the ApprovalResponse (it has getters and setters):  `@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(
    name = "ApprovalResponse",
    propOrder = {"approvalId"}
)
public class ApprovalResponse implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @XmlElement(
        required = true
    )
    protected String approvalId;

    public ApprovalResponse() {
    }

    public String getApprovalId() {
        return this.approvalId;
    }

    public void setApprovalId(String value) {
        this.approvalId = value;
    }
}`.

Comment: add add produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE on your postMapping tag

Comment: I tried adding the MediaType, `produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE` but still get: `org.restlet.resource.ResourceException: Not Acceptable (406) - The resource identified by the request is only capable of generating response entities which have content characteristics not acceptable according to the accept headers sent in the request
`.

Comment: This seems to have helped, because I no longer get the error on the server `Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException: Could not find acceptable representation]`.  But the client still has the same error. So the consumer cannot resolve the response.

Comment: On spring, there is a "Content-Type" Header sent by the client, which states the type of content it can process, so the endpoint you're developing should match the same content-type. What is the "Content-Type" header sent by the client? Knowing it, we could add it in the list of produces on PostMapping annotation.

Comment: If I change them both to `"application/xml"`, the client can call the server with no errors on the server. But the client has this error:  `org.restlet.resource.ResourceException: Internal Server Error (500) - The server encountered an unexpected condition which prevented it from fulfilling the request`

Comment: just as a test, could you put on the client request the parameter at the end _?format=json_   ?

Comment: On the endpoint url?  i.e. `http://localhost:8081/rest/approvals-submit?format=json`. If I do this, I still get the same error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216661/discussion-between-damian229-and-richard).

Comment: the answer has been updated accordingly with our chat @Richard

Comment: do you know why I would get this:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62597822/java-restful-client-cant-call-api-when-running-on-server

Comment: I was traveling,  I will try it on Sunday! Is it ok?

Comment: Thank you. Appreciate your help